# In Odoo 10 users could not create new products

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

After installing Odoo 10 and some of its modules. I successfuly created a new product with the Administrator account. Afterwards new users signed in via the web site to create their accounts. At the end I provided some of them the full access rights, so that they will be able to manage the system:

[image]

But trying to add a new product with any of them fails with the following error message:

> Error while validating constraint
>
> The requested operation cannot be completed due to security
>   restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.
>
> (Document type: product.template, Operation: read) None

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: Select a user that cannot create a new product and screenshot his rights. Paste the image in your post for us to determine.

Comment: Have you done any customization or extended any of the models

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas thanks for suggestion. I've added the screenshot to the description.

Comment: @danidee I've installed some new modules and still at the beginning of the customization phase. But as mentioned before the administrator has the ability to create the products. I thing it has to do with the access rights.

Comment: Yes it has to do with access rights but you have to give us more info. What customisation have you done? Show us the__openerp__. py file of the custom module.

Comment: I found an important detail. This issue occurs only by users, who signed themself in, and their access rights are changed afterwards. That's to say they were customers before they got more access rights. By users created from within the settings menu, the access rights work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recognized that users who signed up on the web page are by default in the group ***Portal***. 
The members of this group have specific access rights and **restricted** menus.
Thus removing these users from the group Portal grants them more rights.

Go to:

> Settings -> Users: Users -> *specific user* -> Edit -> 'Other Extra
>   Rights'

and remove the Tick for **Portal**.

Note: the group 'Public' also restricts the users' access rights.

**Edit**: as Sakr mentioned, the **Developer Mode** needs to be activated in order to change the *'Other Extra Rights'*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The accepted answer, as mentioned in it, is only a workaround for the issue. Could you please edit your answer and mention that the developer mode must be activated in order to have the sub-menu 'Other Extra Rights' ? I will change it then to the accepted answer.

Comment: Good point! Thank you too! It can be a hassle searching for missing settings in odoo.

Answer (score 0):

After some research it turned out that the users that signed themselves to Odoo 10 are automatically considered as customers, thus they belong to a customer group. Even though their right access is modified to a full access, they are still restricted. Therefore the best and quick workaround I found is to delete all these accounts, create them again via the administrator with a (default) password. That works fine as expected.

Hope this could be helpful for someone.